# When is the locate database updated?

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, terminal, search

I use the `locate` command in Terminal regularly. When does its database get updated? On other systems, I could run `updatedb` as root to force it to update.

Note: I know using `mdfind` to search with spotlight is another option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The locate database is updated by the following cronjob:

```
/private/etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate
```

On Most Mac systems, Cron has been replaced by [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html), and you'll find that `/etc/crontab` doesn't exist. The schedule for this scheduled job is determined by launchd, and can be seen with one of the following commands:

```
% cat /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-weekly.plist
    #### SNIP
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>3</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
    <key>Weekday</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
</dict>
```

Or, something a little more user friendly:

```
% open /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-weekly.plist
```

`launchd` will then run the jobs specified in `/etc/periodic/{daily,weekly,monthly}/*`, using this schedule.

Comment: tl;dr version: Saturdays at 3:15 AM local time.

Comment: Or if the mac is sleeping at 3:15 AM Saturday morning, when it wakes.

Comment: Yet another way to see the contents of the plist: `defaults read /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-weekly`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo periodic weekly` is the easiest way to kick it off the weekly script which will call the normal rebuild of the locate database.

As noted `launchd` will start this script Saturdays at 03:15 AM if the mac is running. If the mac is sleeping at that time, it will run when the mac wakes. It won't run if the mac is powered off at the magic moment.

Answer (score 0):

From the locate manpage:

```
FILES
 /var/db/locate.database          locate database
 /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb     Script to update the locate database
 /etc/periodic/weekly/310.locate  Script that starts the database rebuild
```

By default, the database is rebuilt weekly through launchd.  You can run `locate.updatedb` manually to do the update.

Comment: On most Mac systems, `cron` is replaced by launchd. There is no /etc/crontab by default, for example. That was moved to launchd.

Comment: @Stefan - Your right.  I forgot about that change, which Apple did in Tiger.